# Disable database name when generating sql file with liquibase

Tags: java, sql, database, migration, liquibase

When I generate a SQL file with updateSql command of liquibase I get a file where is always written the name of the target database before each table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TARGETDATABASE.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DELETE FROM TARGETDATABASE.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
INSERT INTO TARGETDATABASE.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
UPDATE TARGETDATABASE.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
CREATE TABLE TARGETDATABASE.DATABASECHANGELOG

CREATE TABLE TARGETDATABASE.MD_CONSTRAINT_DETAILS
ALTER TABLE TARGETDATABASE.MD_CONSTRAINT_DETAILS

CREATE TABLE TARGETDATABASE.MD_GROUP_MEMBERS
ALTER TABLE TARGETDATABASE.MD_GROUP_MEMBERS
```

Is there a way to disable the name of the target database before every table?

Comment: Can you provide all your liquibase configuration information and what database you are using, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I just had to remove the last part of my URL where was written the name of the target database. So instead of:

```
--url=jdbc:mariadb://database:3306/target
```

I had to use:

```
--url=jdbc:mariadb://database:3306
```